# How to convert null to string in Event Gridview RowDeleting on Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview, null

i want convert value null to string in Event Gridview RowDeleting on Textbox.
**But error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

**Code Behide:**

```
protected void gvTerm_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txtCountryRate_Te = (TextBox)gvTerm.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCountryRate_Te");                        
            if (txtCountryRate_Te == null)
            {
                txtCountryRate_Te.Text = string.Empty;  //<== Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            }  
}
```

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: You are trying `txtCountryRate_Te.Text` after you've checked `if (txtCountryRate_Te == null)`. That's pointless and of course it either is never entered or results in the exception Show your aspx.

Comment: Tim is pointing out that null means that the variable points to nothing. In order to set the txtCountryRate_Te, you would first have to instantiate an instance of TextBox and then set the value. txtCountryRate_Te = new TextBox();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error exactly tells what is happening. you are trying to access and set property of null object.

to set String.Empty as text to your object. just create new instance of object with empty text.

```
    protected void gvTerm_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtCountryRate_Te = (TextBox)gvTerm.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCountryRate_Te");
        if (txtCountryRate_Te == null)
        {
            txtCountryRate_Te = new TextBox
            {
                Text = String.Empty
            };
        }
    }
```

How ever the default value is String.Empty so you can simplify it to

```
txtCountryRate_Te = new TextBox();
```